# jquery/ ruby on rails - changing the height of a div dynamically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my app I have a page where the user can see all their reviews listed one under the other. Each review has an 'edit' link:

```
<div id ="edit_link">
    <%= link_to I18n.t('user.review.edit.edit'), edit_review_path(review), :remote => true, :class => "edit_review_link" %>
    </div>
```

It loads the editable review on the same page as the other reviews, and user can change it.

It loads with this code in a edit.js.erb file:

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>")
```

Now I'm trying to change the height of this review for editing when it loads. Any ideas how I could do this?

I did try in my edit.js.erb file:

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>")

$('#review_<%= review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 350);
//this method increases the height to 250px, at .35 seconds
```

but I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)` error.

I also did try this, pasting it within the _review.html.erb file:

```
<script>
$('#edit_link').click(function(){
    $('#review_<%= review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 350);
    //this method increases the height to 250px, with speed of .35 seconds
});
</script>
```

but it only toggles properly on the first review, at the top of the list. Also, it increases the size of all reviews below. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you are missing the '@' before the review.id in your javascript (use `<%= @review.id %>` and not `<%= review.id %>`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji - dooh! Works now. Put it in an answer and I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error, you are missing the `@` sign before the variable ;)

Change this:

```
$('#review_<%= review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 350);
```

To this:

```
$('#review_<%= @review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 350);
               ^
               # Here, add the '@'
```